# need help on this assignment for React.js

Tags: reactjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

      /*

      This component is supposed to render the text the user types to the screen. However it is missing some code and is not working correctly. Add to the code below so the component prints what the user types to the screen.

      */
      function InputComponent(props) {

        return (
          <div>
            <label>
              Type some text
            </label>
            <input onChange={props.onInput}/>
          </div>

        );
      }
      class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

        onInput(event) {
          this.setState({
            data: event.target.value
          });
        }
        render() {
          return (
            <div>
              You typed: {this.state.data}
              <InputComponent onInput={this.onInput}/>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(
        <ParentComponent/>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The comment is the question. SO the question is

This component is supposed to render the text the user types to the screen. However it is missing some code and is not working correctly. Add to the code below so the component prints what the user types to the screen.

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: This is more like a "fill in the blanks" exercise than a question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not binding the method you pass to the child component. This means that the "this" inside the method is not referring to the parent component, as you need.
So you should write:

```
<InputComponent onInput={this.onInput.bind(this)}/>
```

Or bind it in the constructor.

Edit:
The problem happens because you are trying to use this.state.data, which you never declared. Inside your ParentComponent, first of all you need to write the constructor, which would be like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    data: ''
  }
  this.onInput = this.onInput.bind(this) // as you are binding the method here, remove it from the props you are passing to the child component.
}
```

Comment: i did that and it still doesnt display anything on the screen and also it tells me cannot read property data of null on the console.